# icon not apear like primeng example

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

why the icon that I implement from primeng not seen like primeng example and not like I need?
code:

```
  <i class="pi pi-info-circle" style="font-size: 2rem"></i>
        <span class=" pi pi-info-circle"></span>
```

looks like:
[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb0ig.png)

primeng example
[primeng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghrqo.png)

what I need [mydesire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Fmf.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of PrimeIcons are you using? Is it before 4.0?.

The icons were updated in version 4.0 and the info-circle icon got a facelift as well, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeicons/commits/master/raw-svg/info-circle.svg). You can click on the "View at this point in the history" button (second button from the right) to see the icon in each of its iterations, with the top-most showing the icon you're looking for.

The demo probably uses the latest version of the library so you're seeing the updated icon there.

Comment: thanks so how can I show the newest version without update prime? use the svg file?

Comment: but then, how can I change it to blue as I need?

Comment: I don't think you need to update the PrimeNG library, only the PrimeIcons library. Or is it a problem as well?

Comment: yes because it a big app so I dont want to change another icons

Comment: Technically you can change the color of an SVG using CSS filters but if you're thinking of dropping the use of the PrimeIcons library for this icon, there are simpler ways to get the icon than use an SVG. For instance, you can simply use the HTML character for it: `&#9432;`. See [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24d8/index.htm).